# make floating divs fill whitespace

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the problem that I have 3 divs and when one div is longer than the other div, it creates some whitespace.
I would like to have the whitespace gone and the divs connect.
This is what I have now:

```css
.one{
background: lightgreen;
height: 300px;
width:100px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
.two{
background: brown;
height: 500px;
width: 100px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
.main{
width: 220px;

}
.info{
background: orange;
height: 200px;
width:100px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
<div class='info'>

to this one

</div>
<div class='two'>



</div>
<div class='two'>
this one should be up


</div>
<div class='two'>



</div>
<div class='one'>



</div>
</div>
```

The only reason I have these classes is because I want to show an example of my problem, In reality all divs have the same class.
Could anyone solve the problem for me?

[image: my problem]
As you can see in my image, the bottom div is not connected to the one above it.
 all divs have float: left;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, when the class `.two` is floating left.
You have to use `float:right` for the class `.two` instead.

```css
.one{
background: lightgreen;
height: 300px;
width:100px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
.two{
background: brown;
height: 500px;
width: 100px;
float: right;
margin: 5px;
}
.main{
width: 220px;

}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
<div class='one'>

to this one

</div>
<div class='two'>



</div>
<div class='one'>
this one should be up


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to float the `.two` class to the right.

```
float: right;
```

Hope this helps :>

```css
.one{
background: lightgreen;
height: 300px;
width:100px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
.two{
background: brown;
height: 500px;
width: 100px;
float: right;
margin: 5px;
}
.main{
width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
<div class='one clearfix'>

to this one

</div>
<div class='two'>



</div>
<div class='one'>
this one should be up


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what If I don't know what element goes under the green element? I have more than just 3 elements and they could differ in height, so does float right still work then?

Comment: It should. Can you add an example

Comment: You solved my problem in the first place, but in my real situation its not the right solution, do you want to help?

Comment: Would love to help. But it will take 3 hours. Im on the move and not on my pc

Comment: Thanks I will contact u then if it still isnt solved

Comment: @JelleBotman Im here and ready to help. Can you update your example with numbers and maybe the side each dive has to go. Example: Left 1 Right 1. This so I can understand what is the desired layout

Comment: It should automaticly move the divs upwards and fill the white space, It shouldn't do it manually so I should not set a div to the left or right manually but my code should do that autmatic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171991/discussion-between-jelle-botman-and-gerardo-blanco).

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:right` to .two div element